# KnockoutJS visible binding

Tags: knockout.js

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fPsK6/2/

Why `visible` binding doesn't work?

Comment: You should always post duplicate source code here so the question doesn't depend on other resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the values of the `IsDefault` properties are strings, which always evaluate to `true`. The only string which does not evaluate to `true` is the empty string.

Here's an [updated working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fPsK6/3/).

In that version I've simply removed the quotes around the numbers (so they are actually numbers, not strings). The number `1` evaluates to `true`, and the number `0` evaluates to `false`. You could of course use literal boolean values instead of numbers (or any other values that evaluate to `true` and `false` appropriately).

**Update** (see comments)

Since your data comes from the server and you can't change it, you can convert the string to a number in the `data-bind` attribute value:

```
<span data-bind="visible: +payload.IsDefault()">
```

Note that you need to call `IsDefault` as a function, rather than just giving a reference to the function. Also note the use of the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_%28Unary_Plus%29), which converts a string to a number.

Here's another [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fPsK6/4/).

Comment: Thanks. I get JSON data from server and all values are strings:
`{"root":[{"payload":{"Name":"AAA", "IsDefault":"1"}}, ...]}` so what is the best way to convert some fields from `string` to `int`?